# Error in magento admin panel login

Tags: php, magento

Unable to login in magento admin panel on localhost also not redirecting the admin panel login page in magento

http://localhost/foldername1/Magento/admin/

I also tried from the below url

http://127.0.0.1/foldername1/Magento/admin/

SHOWING ERROR MESSAGE:

Whoops, our bad...

The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.

```
    If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
    If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.
```

What can you do?
    Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on track with Magento Store.

```
    Go back to the previous page.
    Use the search bar at the top of the page to search for your products.
    Follow these links to get you back on track!
    Store Home | My Account
```

Also in my magento 2.0.4 there is no "code" folder inside app folder to change the varian.php file

Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to put /index.php/ before admin in the url:

http://localhost/foldername1/Magento/index.php/admin/